# How can I access a route for a react chrome extension on a tab that I have opened in the browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

My end goal is to create a chrome extension that will open a new page after clicking a NavLink on the extension's popup. However, the new tab does not seem to have access to any of the Routes I have already created. So, in my App.js file, I have the following render method:

```
render() {
    return (
    <Router><div>
        <Toolbar />
        <Route path="/" render={
            () => {
                return (
                <div>
                    <h1>HELLO!</h1>
                </div>
                );
            }
        }/>

        <Route path="/Profile" render={
            () => {
                return (<Profile />);
            }
        }/>

        <Route path="/Signup" strict render={
            () => {
                return (<Signup />);
            }
        }/>

        <Route path="/Login" strict render={
            () => {
                return (<Login />);
            }
        }/>
    </div></Router>
    );
}
```

And then in Toolbar.js, I have the following render method:

```
render() {
    return (
    <Router><div>
        <Navbar color="dark" expand="md">
            <NavbarBrand><Link to="/" target="_blank">Title</Link></NavbarBrand>
            <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
            <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
                <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
                    <NavItem>
                        <NavLink to="/Profile" exact activeStyle={
                            { color:'green' }
                        }>Profile</NavLink>
                    </NavItem>
                    <NavItem>
                        <NavLink to="/Signup" exact activeStyle={
                            { color:'green' }
                        }>Signup</NavLink>
                    </NavItem>
                    <NavItem>
                        <NavLink to="/Login" exact activeStyle={
                            { color:'green' }
                        }>Login</NavLink>
                    </NavItem>
                </Nav>
            </Collapse>
        </Navbar>
    </div></Router>
    );
}
```

It should be opening index.html with the "/" route and display "HELLO!", but instead it goes to a page that reads:

> This site can’t be reached The webpage at
>   chrome-extension://digmnhpjagkkhhhpfmokdmoejekfdinm/ might be
>   temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web
>   address. ERR_UNEXPECTED

Comment: Extensions aren't web pages, but just a bunch of files, so `/` doesn't resolve to index.html.

Comment: Okay I changed it so the link in Toolbar.js is now "/index.html". Is there a way for it to load a particular route when it loads this file - one that would be different than the popup?